# Financial Accounts - Intersectoral Flow-of-Funds Data

Tags: data-request, finance, federal

I am looking for data that contains financial liabilites/assets of different sectors in an economy to other sectors for different countries. In Europe this is regulated by ESA 2010 (or ESA 95, the older version) and can be found [here](http://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/web/sector-accounts/data/database), the FED issues similar data in its [Z1 release](http://www.federalreserve.gov/releases/z1/current/data.htm).

However, I need the intersectoral data, whereas both sources only deliver them accumulated. As an example, I want to know how many assets households own that are liabilities of the Government. The accumulated version would give the assets households hold originating in the other sectors.

I know that the [German Bundesbank delivers this data](http://www.bundesbank.de/Navigation/EN/Statistics/Time_series_databases/Macro_economic_time_series/its_list_node.html?listId=www_v1f_145gv32) in such a detail, and was wondering where I can find the data from sources that contain more than one country.

Any hint or direction where to look is highly appreciated.

**Addition**

I already talked to Eurostat (the first link), they do not provide intersectoral data. So is the OECD and the UN.

Comment: As I don't have enough reputation to post more than three links yet, but I think the link is vital; here is the link to the German Bundesbank: http://www.bundesbank.de/Navigation/EN/Statistics/Time_series_databases/Macro_economic_time_series/its_list_node.html?listId=www_v1f_145gv32

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the link below, 
is the datasets on multiple counties, I'm not sure if is all free but is a good start point. Is by countries( did not check if all countries are listed, saw for European Central Bank, Swiss, US, Brazil, China etc).

ww.quandl.com

[long-term debt securities database](https://www.quandl.com/search?query=long-term%20debt%20securities)

[image]

Comment: Were you able to locate intersectoral data on Quandl? So far I only found aggregated data. However, I specifically need the intersectorla flows. Such as Households to non-financial companies.

Comment: @David just search for US Flow of Funds and Eurostat ESA95 Databases. So will pull all countries, for US will be all the states and EU for all countries. Both are in Quandl.